# git error when trying to push one commit

Tags: git, push, commit

I am trying to push just one commit to origin master. However I get an error saying I first need to fetch then merge, but I get this error after a pull. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
Richard@RICHARD-PC /e/Work/MH (master)
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.
From file:///V:\
   930430f..3a55dca  master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging project/src/main/java/com/company/project/outgoing/HttpsCallService.java
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .../java/com/company/project/auth/BcagHmacGenerator.java  |  2 +-
 .../com/company/project/outgoing/HttpsCallService.java    | 16 ++--------------
 deployLocal.sh                                           |  2 +-
 3 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)

Richard@RICHARD-PC /e/Work/MH (master)
$ git push origin 72ba712:master
To file:///V:\
 ! [rejected]        72ba712 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'file:///V:\'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Here is the list of commits, not the position of 72ba712:

```
Richard@RICHARD-PC /e/Work/MH (master)
$ git lol
*   eec2ab2 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of file:///V:\
|\
| * 3a55dca (origin/master) <comments>
* | 72ba712 <comments>
* | bc55eb5 <comments>
* |   c2aa448 Merge branch 'master' of file:///V:\
|\ \
| |/
| * 930430f <comments>
* | fc7a55b <comments>
* | fd401a5 <comments>
```

Comment: Are you sure that nobody pushed a new commit between your `git pull` and your `git push`? If there is much activity in the repository this can indeed happen.

Comment: Yes, it's just two of us, and origin is on the other guys pc. He was sitting next to me and made no changes since the pull.

Comment: You don't just push single commits, especially when they're not at the tip of a branch. You push one or more branches which contain the commit you want to push.

Comment: thanks twalberg, but this is a special case where I only want to push one commits changes to origin, and not all the others.

Comment: What I mean is, that's not how `git` works, and in that sense, it doesn't really matter that you want it to work that way... It doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, you have commits that are ahead of your own on `master`. To make sure that you are actually up to date, run your pull as followed:

```
git fetch origin
#then....
git pull origin master
```

This will make sure that you are pulling from the right place, then you can push your committed changes as followed (again being explicit so that git knows what is going where):

```
git push origin master
```

Your error could be coming from your syntax, it is possible you have git configured in some what which is making the way you are pulling now `git pull` ambiguous to git.

Comment: Sure, go for it, but I do not understand how you connectivity to origin could be time sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, unfortunately I can only connect to origin tomorrow. But I have another quick question. If I do the following, will it only push the changes in that commit, or will it push all changes leading up to that commit too? `git push origin 72ba712:master`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to push the commit with hashvalue `72ba712` to the remote master branch but that doesn't work, obviously, without a merge, what you did already. Now, after the merge, you'd have to push the merge commit:

```
git push origin eec2ab2:master
```

or, easier:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```